# Change the text color only of selected text in Vs Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I want to change the color of selected text only not the background so what is the way to do it because I am not getting anything to change the selected text only, I am getting solution to change the background but not the text.

[image: sample image]

Here I have attached one image in which I have selected editor but text color is still green so want the text color in black after selection so is there any way to change it.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Comment: I once asked this related to decorators and the answer was it will be a big performance hit if they allow this, I think the selection is a decorator, decorators are implemented in a different layer compared to syntax highlighting

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a long-time open bug in VS Code:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/36490